# google place api

Tags: android

I need to use google place api in my application for finding nearer all places with respect to perticular place(suppose my current location). But i am not having client id . how to get client id ??? I also have tried to use yahoo locationsearch for this ,but i cant get correct responce from yahoo server. Is there any solution for this ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Placs API is still in developer preview so to get access and get a clientId you need to fill out the [application form.](http://gmaps-ws-console.appspot.com/)